# Assets url Rails 4.1 and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Something always seems to go wrong when deploying an app to heroku, today its my images not being rendered.

I ran

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=produciton
```

committed changes and pushed to heroku

In my view for example i have

```
<%= image_tag('/assets/logo.png') %>
```

but the image is not being rendered because its looking for logo.png as opposed to

```
logo-321321327454547676576586876.png
```

which was generated when running the precompile.. I think im missing an option in my production.rb file somwhere

```
Rails.application.configure do

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = false

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true

config.assets.version = '1.0'

config.log_level = :info

config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

How do i get the app to look for the generated image url created when precompiling? something simple Im guessing

I am going to use an S3 bucket to serve these in the future but am interested in getting it working with Heroku on its own

Thanks

Comment: Is it in app/assets/images?  If so you should just need `image_tag('logo.png')`

Comment: what if the image is in app/assets/photos/logo.png, does it become image_tag(/assets/photos/logo.png') or image_tag(/photos/logo.png')

Comment: @Richlewis: Try `<%= asset-path 'logo.png' %>`.

Comment: That I don't know, but I would assume so.  You can just have sub folders under images and have `image_tag('photos/logo.png')`

Comment: thanks, just tried that after reading docs in more detail :-)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the api docs in more detail and taking Baloo's advice the answer is really simple, just a syntax issue with my path declarations

If your image is under assets just use

```
<%= image_tag('image.ext') %>
```

and if its in a sub directory then use

```
<%= image_tag('sub-dir/image.ext') %>
```

Hope this helps someone else